# Ajax JSON Respone took much time

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, ajax

First: Sorry for my Bad English. I hope you understand me anyway.

So. I have an Ajax request and the JSON file is always rewritten from somewhere else. The new data arrives but at the first change it takes 20-30 seconds until the change is visible (I think this is because of the caching, more about this below). After that, after the first request, it takes only 2 seconds or often shorter. And if I don't change anything for a while the same process begins again.

I think it is either because of the caching or because I use a local HTTP server for the request. And this server I set up with Python, here the code from the server:

```
class ServerHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

 
    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
 
    def do_POST(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE': self.headers['Content-Type'],
                     })
        for item in form.list:
            logging.error(item)
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
 
        with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
            for key in form.keys():
                file.write(str(form.getvalue(str(key))) + ",")




def start_localhost():
    Handler = ServerHandler
 
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", 2029), Handler)
 
    print("serving at port", 2029)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

And that it is the caching would also be funny, because I have the following in my head tag of the HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

What might be worth mentioning, I have this html file open in an Edge WebView window.

And here is my JavaScript Code:

```
          var cur_width;
      var cur_height;
      var cur_pos;
      var cur_right;
      var cur_bottom;
      var cur_brightness;
      var cur_blur;
      var cur_zoom;
      var cur_contrast;
      var cur_invert;
      var cur_sepia;
      var cur_saturate;
      var cur_grayscale;

      function checker() {
        vid = document.getElementById("bg_div");
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:2029/backgrounds/asus/video_settings.json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json_infos) {

          var width = json_infos.width;
          var height = json_infos.height;
          var pos = json_infos.position;
          var right = json_infos.right;
          var bottom = json_infos.bottom;
          var blur = json_infos.blur;
          var brightness = json_infos.brightness;
          var zoom = json_infos.zoom;
          var contrast = json_infos.contrast;
          var invert = json_infos.invert;
          var sepia = json_infos.sepia;
          var saturate = json_infos.saturate;
          var grayscale = json_infos.grayscale;

          var new_filter = "brightness("+brightness+") blur("+blur+") contrast("+contrast+") invert("+invert+") sepia("+sepia+") saturate("+saturate+") grayscale("+grayscale+")";

          if(width != cur_width) {
          cur_width = width;
          vid.style.width = width;
          }

          if(cur_pos != pos) {
          cur_pos = pos;
          vid.style.position = pos;
          }

          if(cur_height != height) {
          cur_height = height;
          vid.style.height = height;
          }

          if(cur_right != right) {
          cur_right = right;
          vid.style.right = right;
          }

          if(cur_bottom != bottom) {
          cur_bottom = bottom;
          vid.style.bottom = bottom;
          }

          if(cur_brightness != brightness) {
          cur_brightness = brightness;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_blur != blur) {
          cur_blur = blur;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_zoom != zoom) {
          cur_zoom = zoom;
          vid.style.transform = zoom;
          }

          if(cur_contrast != contrast) {
          cur_contrast = contrast;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_invert != invert) {
          cur_invert = invert;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_sepia != sepia) {
          cur_sepia = sepia;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_saturate != saturate) {
          cur_saturate = saturate;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }

          if(cur_grayscale != grayscale) {
          cur_grayscale = grayscale;
          vid.style.filter = new_filter;
          }
        }
        
      });
      }

      checker();
      var t = setInterval(checker, 400);
```

EDIT:
The Problem was the Server. He was to slowly, i used PHP (Exe) instead of http Module.

Comment: Please add your code in the question and not a link to the code.

Comment: Sorry, i thinked the Code is too long.

Comment: `var t = setInterval(checker, 400);` You are sending a request to your server every 400ms, no matter if the previous request has finished or not. If you have speed issues, try moving the call to `checker()` inside the success and failure functions of the ajax request, so that you only have one request and wait for it to succeed or fail before sending the next request.

Comment: edit question and put Python code again and use `Ctrl+k` to format it. At this moment Python code has wrong indentation and it is hard to say if it makes some problem.